# np.loadtxt error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Time'

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter

I have a data set located at [this](http://hyperion.usc.edu/courses/ce119/data/Composite_Tensile_exp_1.dat) url.

I am trying to retrieve the number of rows and columns from the data set and I have entered the following:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

url1= "http://hyperion.usc.edu/courses/ce119/data/Composite_Tensile_exp_1.dat"

value_url1 = np.loadtxt(url1)
value_url1.shape

print(value_url1.shape[1])
print('There are' + str(value_url1.shape[1]) + ' columns in url1.')
```

and when I run it I get the following error:

```py
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Time'
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason of the error is that you have string dtype in the first line. According to the [NumPy doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html), the dtype is automatically treated as float.

If you want to make it work, you can do

```
value_url1 = np.loadtxt(url1, skiprows=1)
print(value_url1.shape)
```